# Implement Custom json in extjs treegrid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to implement a code where I need to display data from a JSON into a tree grid, but I am unable to get the desired output. I only see the root node, and when I click on it again, it copies the same node into the second one.

My JSON looks like below:

```
{
  "grandparent": [
    {
      "parent1": [
        {
          "parent2": [
            {
              "parent3": [],
              "id": "aa",
              "name": "abc",
              "grandparentid": "11",
              "specialparams": [
                {
                   "a": "04",
                  "y": "",
                  "x": "asd_123",
                  "z": 0,
                    }]
                  }
               }
               name="text",
               "grandparentid": "11"    
               }
```

In my store, I have mentioned rootProperty as 'grandparent'. Not sure what I am missing.

Expected Output:

```
>grandparent
 >parent1
  >parent2
   >parent3 -- this will be blank
   a:04
   x:asd_123
```

Answer (score 0):

In tree store if you want the node to have child nodes you should set child nodes in `children` property.

In your `JSON` there is no `children` for each `node` and you defined nodes as `array`

Make your `JSON` like:

```
[
{
    id: 1,
    name: "grandparent"
    children: [
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "parent1",
            children: [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: "parent2",
                    children: [
                        ...
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: That means it’s compulsory to have children node to be mentioned in json?

Comment: Not exactly but default behavior is this. but you can write your own json reader if you want. You can find out about how to do that in http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.data.reader.Json.html

Comment: thanks for your input, i will work on it and put comment once completed.